# Using Python Code to read excel files in R with openpyxl and reticulate

Tags: python, r, excel, openpyxl, reticulate

When trying to manipulate excel files from R it was very challenging from me, as there was no good packages that allowed the user to write values into a specific range in excel.
Instead, I had to opt for a Python package called openpyxl and, using reticulate from R to translate the Python code into R code, I managed to import the workbook into R as a Python workbook.
The problem is that the subsequent code to manipulate the imported workbook in R does not work.

Then, writing the code in R I had to do some changes:

This is the Python code:

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\...\Test.xlsx')
sheet = book["User_Interface"]
print(sheet["L11"].value)
sheet["L11"] = 20000000
book.save(r'C:\Users\...\Test.xlsx')
```

which translated into R would be:

```
library(reticulate)
opel <- import('openpyxl')
book <- opel$load_workbook("C:/Users/.../Test.xlsx")
sheet<- book["User_Interface"]
print(sheet["L11"])
```

print(sheet["L11"]) produces the following output in R:

```
> print(sheet["L11"])
<Cell 'User_Interface'.L11>
```

But when trying to print cell "L11" like I did with the Python code, I get an error:

```
print(sheet["L11"]).value
Error: unexpected symbol in "print(sheet["L11"]).value"
```

and the same happens when trying to change the value of a cell in R:

```
> sheet["L11"]=20000000 
Error in sheet["L11"] = 2e+07 : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

I would like to know if there is a guidance to translate the Python code into R code that needs to be used with the R package "reticulate"

Comment: Your first issue could be fixed using `print(sheet["L11"]$value)`. Not an expert using `reticulate` but as far as I remember always use `$` where you use a `.` in python.

Comment: I would challenge your initiaö assumption that there is no good package to write content to a certain Excel range. Check out ar package `openxlsx` which is very powerful!

Comment: Thanks so much stefan. It worked like a charm!! I completely forgot to use the $ sign instead of "."

Comment: Thanks deschen for your comment, but I've tried to use openxlsx and I could not get the workbook loaded into R, as it was full of formulas. To the contrary, openpyxl is not loading the whole workbook, but only using the part that is needed.